# Виртуальное окружение при работе с github

Tags: git, github, virtualenv

Я делаю git clone репозитория с github в какую нибудь папку на моем компе. Вопрос в следующем: мне нужно заранее сделать и активировать виртуальное окружение и туда клонировать репозиторий или виртуальное окружение само создается?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, виртуальое окружение само по себе не создастся.

Операция клонирования репозитория - это не более чем операция над файлами, оа не зависит ни от операционной системы, ни от набора устновленного софта.

Создание же виртуального окружения тесно связано с установленным питоном и затрагивает конфигурацию компа - грубо говоря, при создании VENV у Вас именно в определенные папки устанавливаются определенные библиотеки.

Вообще, "клонирование" и "все, что относится к компиляции - интерпретации - сборке" - это разные процессы.

Я бы стал делать так: склонировал, и вручную создал вируальное окружение.